# how to POST array to Strapi

Tags: react-native, postman, strapi

here is my API get request:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "title": "something",
                "game": "default",
                "players": "static",
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

I would like to set `"Players"` to an array like below:

```
"attributes": {
                "title": "23123",
                "game": "1231",
                "players": [
                      "1" : "static1",
                      "2" : "static2",
                      "3" : static3",
                           ],
            }
```

how can i make this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a component called "Player" from content-type builder and then add this component with repeatable to your main entity type.